# The import com.google cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to do a Map View in android (migrating from iOS). In the android SDK pannel I have google APIs (API 17) installed, which I was hoping would fix the problem. So in my source code I have:

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

And its giving me the error: `The import com.google cannot be resolved`. I have searched google for a result, but they havent worked (most of them were making sure the Google API is installed.

I am on a Macbook Pro, 64 bit using Eclipse ADT downloaded from the android dev site.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: i guess you are using map pai v1 which is depreceated. you should use map api v2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: @Raghunandan Ahh I see, all the info on this is 2011 or before, so that could be why it isnt working. I will look for a tutorial for V2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096745/google-maps-api-v3-shows-gray-boxes-only/17097135#17097135. similar question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add the library to your project.

You can find the .jar file in your sdk
`sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\libs\maps.jar`

Thread about how to add a library in your android project :
[Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: If you're using `ant` to build your project, just copying maps.jar to `libs/` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the build target (Project > Properties > Android) to be a build target that has the Google APIs in it, to use Maps V1.

That being said, Raghunandan is correct -- you should be using Maps V2, as you can no longer get Maps V1 API keys. Note that Maps V2 does *not* require you to have a "Google APIs" build target.